# How can Https links from Google search be redirected to Http after the SSL was removed from site?

Tags: wordpress, ssl

Recently I added SSL to my WordPress site but it started causing some problems (conflicts with Woocommerce and WP Super Cache plugins). The problem the I was having because of SSL was that the the Woocommerce cart was sometimes showing empty even after adding a product ans sometime the cart was not proceeding to checkout page. Do you think it had something to do with WP Super Cache or SSL or both? Anyway, I couldn't get it solved and removed the SSL after 2 days. But meanwhile Google had indexed the HTTPS URLs of my site and was showing them in the search results and they were returning SSL connection error. Now my question is how can I redirect all those HTTPS URLs to the HTTP ones? I asked my web host for help but said the redirection is not possible through htaccess or any other method. Was he right? How long will Google take to 'forget' these HTTPS links and show the HTTPS links again in search Results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two standard ways to redirect:

- At the DNS level
- At the HTTP level

The DNS level can't help you because it just changes hostname. You want to keep the same hostname but change the scheme. This means you need an HTTP server to do the redirect.

In order to redirect from `https` to `http` you need to have an HTTPS service running on the computer with the IP address that the hostname resolves to.

Without that, there is nothing the receive the HTTP request over SSL and response with "Oh, this has moved to plain HTTP".

If the SSL service isn't running, then there is nothing that can do that.

(.htaccess is just a (suboptimal) means to configure an HTTP server, that does no good if you don't have the HTTP server listening on SSL).

Comment: I see. But I do't have the SSL now. Looks like I can do nothing but to wait for Google to reindex the http version of my site.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd fix the https issues. The world is going more https everyday so it's a backwards step to go from https to http. If you elaborate on what issues you had someone might be able to help.

However if you really want to do this then you need to run both http and https and redirect all traffic from https to http. How you do this depends on your set up (in Apache you'd do it using htaccess config).

How long it takes Google to fronded your site depends on many factors including the size and popularity of your site - which governs how often Google crawls your website. Give it a month at least for a small site. You can give it a kick by submitting your site to Google Search Console (the new name for Google Webmaster Tools).

Btw StackOverflow is primarily for programming questions so questions like this might be better asked on the http://webmasters.stackexchange.com sister site.

Comment: Thank you. I asked my web host for help but said the redirection is not possible through htaccess or any other method. Was he right? I have already resubmmited the sitemap in Google Webmaster Tools and also used the Fetch as Google tool. Sorry for putting the question in the qrong section. It was my first post on StackOverflow.

Comment: Redirection is possible through htaccess. Note however you will need a valid SSL certificate (which I presume you had already from when it was a https site) as the secure connection is made first, and then the redirection can happen.

Comment: I see. But I do't have the SSL now. Looks like I can do nothing but to wait for Google to reindex the http version of my site. The problem the I was having because of SSL was that the the Woocommerce cart was sometimes showing empty even after adding a product ans sometime the cart was not proceeding to checkout page. Do you think it had something to do with WP Super Cache or SSL or both?